# Laravel "Cannot redeclare class App\Login" for user model (Login) after upgrade to 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I have decided to upgrade Laravel to 5.2. Ever since the upgrade I can't interact with the user (called Login in my case) model anymore due to an error.

The error: `FatalErrorException in Login.php line 6: Cannot redeclare class App\Login`

I already executed stuff such as `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload` but that does not seem to fix this. If I remove the Login model just to see what will happen, it will display that the model is not found. Note that my models are located at App\Models.

I probably overlooked something or made a silly mistake, any help is appreciated.

My App/Models/Login.php file looks like:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Login extends Model{

    use Authenticatable;

    protected $primaryKey = 'AID';
    protected $table = 'Login';
    protected $fillable = ['userid', 'Password'];
    protected $hidden = ['Password'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function getAuthPassword() {
        return $this->Password;
    }
}
```

config/auth.php file:

```
<?php
return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => 'App\Models\Login',
        ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'email' => 'emails.password',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Autoload section in composer.json:

`"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Libraries",
        "app/Models"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},`

Comment: Shouldn't the namespace be App\Models? That's what you have in your auth.php config

Comment: Did you copy-paste the code in some other model and forget to change the name of model class in there?

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo correct, that fixed part of the problem. I'll post my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had to fix my namespace and I had to implement the AuthenticatableContract interface. The following fixed it:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Login extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract{

    use Authenticatable;

    protected $primaryKey = 'AID';
    protected $table = 'Login';
    protected $fillable = ['userid', 'Password'];
    protected $hidden = ['Password'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function getAuthPassword() {
        return $this->Password;
    }
}
```